# Combining columns from multiple files

Tags: r

I am trying to combine columns form multiple files but I get an error message that affects the merging of some of my files. I am not sure where the error occurs, any idea?

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.mirna")

library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(file_list, function(x) 
  fread(x, select=c("mir", "seq", "freq","mism","add","t5","t3"))[, 
                                                                  list(ID=paste(mir, seq, mism,add,t5,t3), freq=freq)])
miraligner <- as.data.frame(Reduce(function(x,y) x[y, on = "ID"], lst))
head(miraligner)
```

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In fread(x, select = c("mir", "seq", "freq", "mism", "add", "t5",  :
>   Bumped column 9 to type character on data row 6, field contains 'g'. Coercing 
>   previously read values in this column from logical, integer or numeric back to 
>   character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they 
>   will now be just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and 
>   ',NA,' too (if they occurred in this column before the bump). If this matters please 
>   rerun and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this column. Please note that column 
>   type detection uses the first 5 rows, the middle 5 rows and the last 5 rows, so 
>   hopefully this message should be very rare. If reporting to datatable-help, please 
>   rerun and include the output from verbose=TRUE.
> 2: In fread(x, select = c("mir", "seq", "freq", "mism", "add", "t5",  :
>
> Bumped column 9 to type character on data row 16, field contains 't'. Coercing 
>   previously read values in this column from logical, integer or numeric back to 
>   character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they 
>   will now be just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and 
>   ',NA,' too (if they occurred in this column before the bump). If this matters please 
>   rerun and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this column. Please note that column 
>   type detection uses the first 5 rows, the middle 5 rows and the last 5 rows, so 
>   hopefully this message should be very rare. If reporting to datatable-help, please 
>   rerun and include the output from verbose=TRUE.
> ```

My files look like this:

```
> head(Xfile)
                           seq          name freq             mir start end mism   add t5 t3       s5       s3    DB     precursor ambiguity
1        AACTGGTTGAACAACTGAACC seq_100018_x3    3  hsa-miR-582-3p    54  74    0     0  t  0 ATTGTAAC AACCCAAA miRNA   hsa-mir-582         1
2       TAGCACCATTTGAAATCAGTGT seq_10002_x43   43  hsa-miR-29b-3p    52  73    0     0  0  t TATCTAGC TGTTTTAG miRNA hsa-mir-29b-2         1
3 TGAGTGTGTGTGTGTGAGTGTGTGTTTT seq_100046_x3    3  hsa-miR-574-5p    25  49    0 I-TTT  0 GT CGTGTGAG GTGTGTCG miRNA   hsa-mir-574         1
4        GTCATACACGGCTCTCCTCTC seq_100072_x3    3  hsa-miR-485-3p    46  66    0     0  0  t GCGAGTCA CTCTTTTA miRNA   hsa-mir-485         1
5      CTGGACTTGGAGTCAGAAGGCAC seq_100077_x3    3 hsa-miR-378a-3p    44  64    0  I-AC  a  0 TAGCACTG   AGGCCT miRNA  hsa-mir-378a         1
6      TAACACTGTCTGGTAACGATGGT seq_100080_x3    3 hsa-miR-200a-3p    54  74    0  I-GT  0  t ACTCTAAC ATGTTCAA miRNA  hsa-mir-200a         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to care about this one.

Your 9th column (t5) contains 0 or letters. 
`fread` tries to autoguess the type of a variable based on few records (5).

For those files where the 5 first records contain only 0, it autoguess as numeric. Such as when it encounters a '"t" or a "a" it switches to charaters, being fancy enough to inform you.

Comment: No, fread fails to combine the files when there is more than a certain number of files.